# Use org.hibernate.validator.internal.cfg.context for creating constraint on a method

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I am currently working on refactoring a piece of code because it looks like hibernate guys have a bad track record with version compatibilities.

We were using `hibernate-validator-5.0.2.Final` initially and I have to upgrade it to `hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final`. The public classes eg : `ConfiguredConstraint.java` have been changed to non-public and they don't seem to work anymore now !

I could see a lot of new methods and classes introduced but kind of stuck with the usage.

I need to create constraint on `method` and there are N number of methods now which I am not able to figure which one to use from this package : `org.hibernate.validator.internal.cfg.context`

I know this is a very abstract information but if anyone has any idea how to approach this and implement on a high level, would appreciate that !

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use stuff from the `internal` package directly.

See the example 12.8 of https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api .

```java
HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
        .byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
        .configure();

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
    .type( Car.class )
        .constructor( String.class )
            .parameter( 0 )
                .constraint( new SizeDef().min( 3 ).max( 50 ) )
            .returnValue()
                .valid()
        .method( "drive", int.class )
            .parameter( 0 )
                .constraint( new MaxDef().value( 75 ) )
        .method( "load", List.class, List.class )
            .crossParameter()
                .constraint( new GenericConstraintDef<>(
                        LuggageCountMatchesPassengerCount.class ).param(
                            "piecesOfLuggagePerPassenger", 2
                        )
                )
        .method( "getDriver" )
            .returnValue()
                .constraint( new NotNullDef() )
                .valid();
```

And then you build your `ValidatorFactory` from this configuration.

Comment: I already have a Parent class which contains the constraint creation using programmatic declaration for the fields which are common to multiple child classes.
But in each of my individual child class I need to create constraint on a specific method.
If I am trying the same programmatic approach I am getting a validation exception :

```<ClassName> is configured more than once via the programmatic constraint declaration API.```

The constraint needs to be declared on the same <ClassName> as it contains the fields on which constraint is declared & method for which I have to make constraint